# POSTGRESQL: How to get all possible values for column with type enum array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, enums

I've been trying to get all the possible values of a column whose type is an array of enum (`ENUM[]`) in Postgresql using a SQL request.

The usual method that uses the field `data_type` from the table `information_schema.columns` doesn't work  as it only returns `ARRAY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked:

```sql
SELECT enumlabel
FROM pg_enum
         INNER JOIN pg_type ON enumtypid = typelem
         INNER JOIN information_schema.columns ON typname = udt_name
         INNER JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid = typnamespace
WHERE table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
  AND column_name = 'COLUMN_NAME'
  AND nspname = 'public'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `psql`, you can simply use `\dT+`:

```
\dT+ t_enum 
                                       List of data types
 Schema  │  Name  │ Internal name │ Size │ Elements │  Owner  │ Access privileges │ Description 
═════════╪════════╪═══════════════╪══════╪══════════╪═════════╪═══════════════════╪═════════════
 laurenz │ t_enum │ t_enum        │ 4    │ one     ↵│ laurenz │                   │ 
         │        │               │      │ two     ↵│         │                   │ 
         │        │               │      │ three    │         │                   │ 
(1 row)
```

Comment: It does answer the question but I was looking for a SQL request. I edited the question. Thanks for your answer!